# Need some simpler books than Algebraic Geometry I Complex Projective Varieties by David Mumford

Tags: algebraic-geometry, book-recommendation

Right now I am reading David Mumford's book-Algebraic Geometry I Complex Projective Varieties, from the 3ed chapter, too much proofs lead me to lost in the book. I need more suitable for beginner so I can read David Mumford's book, that is with more examples and explanations. Or, some other books you think are suitable for me. I have some backgound on functional analysis, commutative algebra by A&M, Bertrametti et al. "Lectures on Curves, Surfaces and Projective Varieties".

Comment: I quite like Fulton's Algebraic Curves, or milnes AG notes, as an intro, since they are both classically focused, while still introducing the key ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry by Smith, K., Kahanpää, L., Kekäläinen, P., Traves

Is a great place to start, covers lots of material in an informal way, with lots of diagrams and intuitive explanations. It's perfect before starting a more formal study.

As mentioned in the comment by @jgon Milne has lecture notes on his site https://www.jmilne.org/math/ which provide an excellent introduction (as well as fantastic notes on a range of other subjects)

Comment: hi, I have read this book last year,  this book is suitable for beginners as the first book. I double checked the theorems or proofs which I am stuck in, I think my problem mainly lies in algebra, this book uses some tricks or theorems, i did not cover right now, and the style of this book is very differently from the A&M book. I accept @jaon's advice and read milnes AG notes. After two chapters, everything is okey.

Comment: Great, glad you found something that worked for you, if @jgon makes their comment an answer you can accept it, otherwise I will update my answer to include their recommendation and you can accept that if you like.